# Haskell parsing with parsec

Tags: haskell

I'm fairly new to Haskell programming. I am currently trying to familiarize myself with some source code for parsing with parsec.

Two things struck me:

```
type Parser = String -> Tree
```

According to the author, this is supposed to be a declaration of a function? That should actually look like this:

```
Parser :: String -> Tree right?
```

Another ambiguity is in the following code:

```
item :: Parser Char
item = P (\inp -> case inp of......
```

From my understanding this is a type declaration of a function right?

Shouldn't this be

```
item :: Parser -> Char
```

Thanks for helping me

Best regards Christoph

Comment: Given `Parser = type String -> Tree`, `item:: Parser Char` doesn't make any sense to me. `Parser` doesn't take any type parameters. But I'm a Haskell noob, so maybe I'm missing something. Can you give a link to the example that you are following?

Comment: Should it be `item :: Parse**c** Char`?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I assume you are looking at [this slide deck](https://people.engr.tamu.edu/hlee42/csce314/lec09-haskell-parsers.pdf).  What the author actually says is:

> In a functional language such as Haskell, parsers can naturally be viewed as *functions*.

> ```
> -- A parser is a function that takes a string 
> -- and returns some form of a tree
> type Parser = String -> Tree
> ```

What the author means by this is that parsers are functions, and the *type* of such a parser function might be the type `Parser`, which the author has defined as a type alias for the type `String -> Tree`.

That is, after defining the type alias `Parser` using:

```
type Parser = String -> Tree
```

an actual parser could be declared to have type `Parser` (equivalent to type `String -> Tree`) like so:

```
-- here is a very bad parser capable of parsing only one possible program
myTreeParser :: Parser
myTreeParser "2*3+4" = Plus (Times (Num 2) (Num 3)) (Num 4)
myTreeParser _ = error "Parser only supports the program '2*3+4'"
```

Consider the similar statement:  "In a language supporting algebraic data types such as Haskell, points can natually be represented as pairs of floating point numbers:  `type Point = (Double, Double)`.  The intention is not to define such a point but rather to describe the type of points by means of a type alias `Point` that is defined to be equivalent to the type `(Double, Double)` of pairs of floating point numbers.

The author goes on to refine the `Parser` type, pointing out that (1) parsers may not use all of their input and so should return `(Tree, String)` and not just `Tree`, (2) they may be able to parse their input in multiple ways (most importantly in "zero" ways, if the input cannot be parsed) and so should return a list of possible parse results `[(Tree, String)]`, and (3) may need to parse something other than a `Tree` and so ought to be generalized to parse input into an arbitrary type:

```
type Parser a = String -> [(a, String)]
```

This defines a type alias `Parser` that is *parameterized*, meaning that `Parser` itself is not a complete type, but rather `Parser Tree` or `Parser Char` or `Parser Double` is a complete type, representing a parser that parses a `Tree`, `Char`, or `Double`.

So the declaration:

```
item :: Parser Char
```

is correct as written.  Using the final version of this `Parser` type alias:

```
type Parser a = String -> [(a, String)]
```

the type `Parser Char` is equivalent to the type:

```
String -> [(Char, String)]
```

That is, `item`'s type is that of a parser that accepts an input `String` and attempts to parse the beginning of the input to generate a `Char` value, plus the remainder of the `String` after the portion that was parsed.  Ultimately, it returns zero or more such possible parses.  (This particular definition of `item` returns either an empty list of zero parses, indicating no parse is possible, or a singleton list of precisely one parse, indicating the parse was successful.)

Answer (score 1):

> ```
> type Parser = String -> Tree
> ```
>
> According to the author, this is supposed to be a declaration of a function? That should actually look like this:

More precisely, `Parser` is a type alias for the type `String -> Tree` which is a function which takes a `String` and returns a `Tree`.

So `Parser` is a new type name.

On the other hand, compare that to

```
Parser :: String -> Tree
```

This declares a function with the name `Parser` that has the type `String -> Tree`. So in one the first case we declare a new type and in the second case we declare a name with a particular type.

As mentioned in the comment, this should be

```
parser :: String -> Tree
```

because function names should start with lowercase and type names start with uppercase.

Comment: For the latter it probably should be `parser`, since functions start with lowercase.

Comment: @WillemVanOnsem Thanks for the suggestion. It's been a while since I wrote any haskell. Does the compiler enforce this and capitalization for type names? Or is it a convention for us mere humans?

Comment: yes, this is enforced.